# Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Tags: mysql

my $result and $result2 is correct but why this warning occurs "mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in..."
HELP ME TO SOLVE THIS PROBLEM.
This is my coding:

> //capture input

```
       <?php
        //capture input
        $destination_name   = $_POST['destination_name'];
        $num_of_passenger   = $_POST['num_of_passenger'];
        $reserve_to     = $_POST['reserve_to'];
        $venue              = $_POST['venue'];
        $day                = $_POST['day'];
        $DepDate            = $_POST['DepartureDate'];
        $DepartureTime      = $_POST['DepartureTime'];
        $ReDate         = $_POST['ReturnDate'];
        $ReturnTime     = $_POST['ReturnTime'];
```

> STEP 3 : SQL Statement (INSERT UPDATE DELETE VIEW)

```
        $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO location (destination_code, destination_name) VALUES ('','$destination_name')");
        $new_row_id1 = mysql_insert_id();


        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $destination_name   = $row['destination_name'];
        }


        $result2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO reservation (reservation_id, num_of_passenger, reserve_to, venue, day, DepartureDate, DepartureTime, ReturnDate, ReturnTime, destination_code, user_id) VALUES('','$num_of_passenger','$reserve_to','$venue','$day','$DepDate','$DepartureTime','$ReDate','$ReturnTime','$new_row_id1','$_SESSION[user_id]')"); 

    while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($result2))
    {
        $num_of_passenger   = $row2['num_of_passenger'];
        $reserve_to         = $row2['reserve_to'];
        $venue              = $row2['venue'];
        $day                = $row2['day'];
        $DepDate            = $row2['DepartureDate'];
        $DepartureTime      = $row2['DepartureTime'];
        $ReDate             = $row2['ReturnDate'];
        $ReturnTime         = $row2['ReturnTime'];

    }


        if (!$result2)
            {
                die ("Cannot Execute Query".mysql_error());
            }
            else
            {
                print "Reservation Complete";   
            }   

        ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

See Docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

> For other type of SQL statements, **INSERT**, **UPDATE**, **DELETE**, **DROP**, etc, **mysql_query**() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error.

So your code `while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))`, `$result2` is a boolean indicating true/false. You'll need to use a different query (SELECT) to get results to iterate over.